# Expanding the SearchActionItem without adding to backstack

Tags: android

I have a search results page Activity that has a SearchView widget in the actionbar. In onCreateOptionsMenu(), I expand it automatically and display the query like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)searchMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchMenuItem.expandActionView(); // expand the search item
    searchView.setQuery(query, false); // hide the keyboard
    searchView.clearFocus();
    return true;
}
```

The home button is set like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

but when the user hits the back or up buttons, the search closes first and then you have to press once again to close the Activity. How can I force the Activity to finish immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is `finish()` your `Activity` as soon as the `SearchView` is collapsed by implementing an `OnActionExpandListener`:

```
searchMenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
    finish();
    return true;      
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {  
    return true;      
  }
});
```

Comment: @A--C Some problem with bkurzius but... when i add the search item onaction expand listener, the activity closed imediately.

Comment: @fawwaz If you haven't found a solution, create a new question and remember to include your LogCat stack trace.